# MySQL - Issue with backups

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL so please have some patience...

I have been tasked with refreshing a particular UAT Schema, however when I've restored the Schema not all of the tables are present.

Details are as follows; -

The size of the schema is 75Gb

The six largest tables contain 2.3Gb, 3.3Gb, 4.8Gb, 13.6Gb, 15.2Gb and 33.8Gb of data.

The method for the backup is a Windows Server scheduled task running a .bat file, the command for the backup is:

```
REM BH 26/05/19
@echo on
net use z: /delete /y
Net use z: "\\THE NETWORK SHARE NAME"
set mydate=%date:/=%
set mytime=%time::=%
set mytimestamp=%mydate: =_%_%mytime:.=_%

set dbname=schemaname

set filename="E:\Backup\%dbname%-%mytimestamp%.sql"
set filename2="E:\Backup\%dbname%-%mytimestamp%.tz"
echo %filename%
cd "E:\Backup"
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqldump.exe" %dbname% --user=??? --password=??? --host=localhost --port=3306 --quick --lock-tables=false --result-file=%filename% --default-character-set=utf8 --single-transaction=TRUE
```

I am using MySQL Workbench to perform the restore, the restore completes but there are over a 150 tables missing.

Note the following: -
Account running the backups has access to all areas of MySQL
New Dump files are created every three hours
I have been using the latest dump files
Many Thanks

Comment: mysqldump doesn't use any black box binary format. The resulting files are plain SQL code, which you should be able to inspect with any text editor or tool that supports those file sizes.

Comment: Update.

I've just examined one of the recent dump files and the missing tables/data are not included in the dump file.